# trigger opacity while rotating, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, opacity

On click, image rotates. In between those milliseconds when image is rotating I need to increase opacity to 1, when rotation stops - opacity changes back to default .3

I guess I need a conditional statement...

```
$("#image").css('opacity','.3');
var value = 0;
$( "li" ).click(function() {
    var text=$(this).text();
    if(text==="Link1"){value=0;}
    if(text==="Link2"){value=20;}
    if(text==="Link3"){value=40;}
    $("#image").rotate({ animateTo:value});
    while {
        $("image").animate({opacity:'1'},{duration:300});
    } 
    else {
        $("image").animate({opacity:'.3'},{duration:300});
    }
});
```

not sure if `.animate` and `duration` are best practices either...

here is [jsfiddle.net/x9ja7/419/](http://jsfiddle.net/x9ja7/419/) without the conditional statement. with the given example, it doesn't function. in example images opacity even on animation is .3, which is not welcome.

Hope solution is not far away...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use callback parameter in your `rotate` function to call a function when your rotation is finished , like this

**EDITED**

```
$("#image").css('opacity','.3');
var value = 0;
var prev_value = 0;
$( "li" ).click(function() {
    var text=$(this).text();
    if(text==="Link1"){value=0;}
    if(text==="Link2"){value=20;}
    if(text==="Link3"){value=40;}
    if(prev_value != value){
        $("#image").animate({opacity:'1'});
        $("#image").rotate({
            animateTo:value,
            callback: function(){$("#image").animate({opacity:'0.3'});}
        });
    }
    prev_value = value;
});
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x9ja7/470/)..

Comment: I just visited my link and it works fine. ^^ Please explain further if you don't mind..

Comment: @user26409021 one thing though... on repeated click image stays with opacity 1. how can I prevent this?

Comment: Check out my edited answer.. It happens because the rotate function doesn't call the callback function.. So, the work around will be to add another variable to compare the current value with previous value..

Answer (score 1):

You can check if you changed the value of the rotation angle. If you changed it then change and the opacity, otherwise do nothing.

Try this:

```
$("#image").css('opacity','.3');
var value = 0,last=0;
$( "li" ).click(function() {
    var text=$(this).text();
    if(text==="Link1"){value=0;}
    if(text==="Link2"){value=20;}
    if(text==="Link3"){value=40;}
    $("#image").rotate({ animateTo:value});
    if(last!=value){
    $("#image").animate({opacity:'1'},300,function() {
    $("#image").animate({opacity:'0.3'},{duration:300});
    });}
    last=value;
  });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x9ja7/462/)